# Select traz resultados diferentes

Tags: sql

Estou com um problema em um SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM documento WHERE idAdministrador = '1' AND modulo = 'funcionario' OR modulo = 'atestado'
```

Preciso que, se modulo for funcionario OU atestado, que faça a busca correta... Porém, ele não busca os que tem idAdministrador = '1', a base de consulta é o módulo apenas... Retorna independente do idAdministrador ser 1 ou não.

Como faço um SELECT que busque pelo ID primeiro, e se for modulo funcionario ou atestado, liste corretamente?

Comment: `idAdministrador = '1' AND (modulo = 'funcionario' OR modulo = 'atestado')` ?

Comment: Poste como resposta. Deu certo, agradeço demais!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agrupe as condições da sql com `()`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    documento 

WHERE 
    idAdministrador = '1' 
    AND (modulo = 'funcionario' OR modulo = 'atestado')
```

Da outra forma provavelmente estava sendo interpretado como `idAdminstrador=1 e modulo='funcionario` **ou** `modulo='atestado'`.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado! :)

Comment: @AndréBaill tranquilo. Precisando estamos ai.